# How to prevent non-domain computers to redirect local resources in a RDP sessions

Tags: security, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I'd like to prevent users using a non-domain computer from using the 'Redirect local resources' function of Remote Desktop Connection, while they attempt to connect our RD SH server in the domain.

The idea is that kind of computers may be unsafe and should not be granted the right to copy files to our RD SH server via their clipboard, etc...

Anybody knows a solution ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A far better solution would be to block the redirection on the server side - either by using the console utility RDS Host Configuration, or by setting a GPO that applies to those terminal servers.

If that solution is irrelevant, than you could configure RDP files on the stations one by one, but then again, the end user will be able to change it.

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is to allow domain PCs to use redirection. Only non-domain PC should be denied the right to use redirection. We have some clients using their own PC to connect to RD SH via VPN.

Comment: We had the same dilemma. I couldn't find a solution, since the redirection settings are per computer (so it can't be done by the current user logging in) and the redirection is part of the RDP protocol (so it's, at the very least, hard to apply). What we did was to config a dedicated RD server for those connecting from the outside, and hardening the settings on the server and firewall accordingly.